# Why does XWarpPointer only work once (while in a loop)?

Tags: c, x11, cursor-position

Why does XWarpPointer only work once?

When I run:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

int main()
{
  Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
  while (1) {
    Window root_window;
    root_window = XRootWindow(dpy, 0);
    XSelectInput(dpy, root_window, KeyReleaseMask);
    XWarpPointer(dpy, None, root_window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    XSync(dpy, False);
  }
}
```

The mouse should appear locked in a single position. But it only moves the mouse once and then lets me move it around while the loop is still runnning. What is causing the XWarpPointer to only run once? Is it some kind of X11 feature to protect the user from the application?

FYI, I am running RHEL 5.2 on VMWare Fusion on Mac OSX 10.6.

Update:

- When running the binary, components
  like a button or icon flicker, but
  the visual mouse cursor stays where I
  move it.
- After the one time XWarpPointer does
  work, when I move the mouse, the
  cursor jumps to near where it was
  before I warped it. It's as if there
  is a (last_x,last_y) that is not
  getting updated.
- When I change the pointer via
  OpenVMTools it seems to make the
  pointer stick to the desired location
  more, but the visual pointer does not
  change.

Thanks,
Chenz

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124446/xlib-lock-mouse-position-mouse-wrap

Comment: That question (4124446) is _not_ related. I am aware of the Xlib call for centering a mouse. But it appears to not behave as documented.

Comment: *This* question is related... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155282/moving-the-mouse-pointer-in-c-fails-on-linux

Comment: 4 years late, I tried your code and it works just fine on Arch Linux in awesomewm. `XFlush` instead of `XSync` works too.

Answer (score 1):

I've no experience here but what happens if you don't discard events in XSync?  e.g. `XSync(dpy, True);`?

Comment: No observable difference. I even removed XSync call all together, and no difference. There was one new thing I noticed (as mentioned in the update to the question.)

Comment: Basing this off the Wine code they use for implementing SetCursorPos(x,y) it maps to this: `XWarpPointer( data->display, root_window, root_window, 0, 0, 0, 0, x - virtual_screen_rect.left, y - virtual_screen_rect.top );`  Seems like the differnce is they specify root_window instead of None for src window?  http://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/blob?f=dlls/winex11.drv/mouse.c#l1169

Comment: Nope, no change.... thanks for the insight though! I am researching into seeing how VMWare does the virtualization of the pointer. My thought is that I am setting the pointer in the guest os correctly, but to be "virtualized" I must set the pointer in the host as well. (Perhaps the X11 I am running is not uptodate enough to do this for me.)

Comment: As noted above, I was able to set the host (reported) pointer from the guest OS. It did have an effect, but the visual pointer did not change. I can only guess that the two are separate or something is hardware controlled.

Comment: what happens if you use Xflush(dpy) rather than Xsync ?

Answer (score 1):

After

```
XWarpPointer(dpy, None, root_window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Try

```
XFlush(dpy);
```

This should solve the problem.